# Ubuntu 16.04 - Force unmount NFS on shutdown/reboot

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, systemd

Ever since this latest version of Ubuntu and systemd waits I've been plagued by hung systems. Occasionally I'll do work on the network and/or shares and when rebooting Ubuntu will hang perpetually waiting to unmount the NFS share.

I'm not familiar with systemd's dependency tree. How can I force an NFS unmount first-thing on reboot - before Ubuntu gets stuck in eternity?